# WebSQL unsupported in Office for Mac client enviornment

Tags: office365, office-js, office365-apps, ydn-db

We are using indexedDB/WebSQL to store data locally in our Excel Task-pane add-in. While this works on all other environments, we are seeing it fail in Office for Mac client. 
While **vorlon.js shows that WebSQL is supported** when running inside the taskpane, actual call to open a websql DB fails with "DOM Exception 18"

stack:

> openDatabase@[native code]
>   connect@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:307:334
>   Ff@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:180:132
>   A@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:177:384
>   Re@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:177:13
>   Mg@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:188:345
>   X@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:191:82
>   cj@http://localhost:8081/ydn.db-dev.js?v=1:333:405 global
>   code@http://localhost:8081/todo.js:17:28

You can find the simple add-in we used for testing here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuIKF3TQj25mrxzPbJSPSaRVqNDg

Is there a way to enable WebSQL support in Office for Mac client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, Office add-in use web worker environment. In this case, Safari does not support neither indexedDB or WebSQL at the moment.

From [Safari 9 release note](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/), indexedDB support in Web worker is coming.

If there is not database support, I guess there is not workaround.